# Instantiate a concrete Java class that uses recursive generics in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, interop

Can I instantiate a concrete Java class that uses recursive generics in Kotlin, if so then how?

**Details**

I am trying to instantiate a Java class that uses recursive generics similar to the example below. I found a work around for wrapping the Java class in a new class, but that feels like I am sidestepping a problem that I should be able to handle directly.

*Java Class With Recursive Generics*

```
public class MyLegacyClass<T extends MyLegacyClass<T>> {
    // implementation ...
}
```

*How it is Instantiated in Java*

```
// In Java we just ignore the generic type...
MyLegacyClass myLegacyClass = new MyLegacyClass();
```

*Failed Attempts to Instantiate in Kotlin*

```
class myClass {
    // Error: One type argument expected for class...
    val x: MyLegacyClass = MyLegacyClass()

    // Still 'Error: One type argument expected for class..' You start to see the problem here. 
    val y: MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClass>>> = MyLegacyClass()
}
```

*Kotlin workaround*

```
class MyLegacyClassWrapper : MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClassWrapper>()

class myClass {
    val x: MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClassWrapper> = MyLegacyClassWrapper()
}
```

Comment: Instantiating it in Java this way is a bad idea, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I you stating that instantiating an generic object using raw types is a bad idea? (if so, I would agree. I just want to make sure I understand you comment)

Comment: Yes (as a specific case of a more general statement that using raw types is a bad idea unless you have requirements to maintain compatibility with pre-Java-5 code/JVM).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I instantiate a concrete Java class that uses recursive generics in Kotlin? if so then how?

**No, you can't**.
The problem is related to variance.

This Java class:

```
public class MyLegacyClass<T extends MyLegacyClass<T>> {}
```

is equal to this Kotlin class:

```
class MyLegacyClass<T : MyLegacyClass<T>>
```

that is **invariant** in its parameter `T`. You would need instead a **covariant** type, so, in this case:

```
class MyLegacyClass<out T : MyLegacyClass<T>>
```

But you **can't** do it without creating a new Kotlin class due to Java interoperability.

I would move the class `MyLegacyClass` to Kotlin covariant in its parameter `T` if possible, otherwise, your approach is correct.

Comment: If it was converted to Kotlin and used the signature `class MyLegacyClass<out T : MyLegacyClass<T>>`, what would the instantiation then look like?

Comment: @MikeRylander it will look like: `val x = MyLegacyClass<MyLegacyClass<*>>()`

Comment: The Java interoperability issue you referenced to is that Kotlin interprets that as invariant instead of covariant?

Comment: @MikeRylander Exactly